# Run only one instance of a build on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have an agent queue in VSTS with several agents and I have a build assigned to this queue. Is there any way of telling VSTS that only one instance of the build should be run at a time, and the other instances (scheduled on other agents) should wait until the previous one finishes?

I need this because the tests create a temp database on which integration tests are run and if multiple instances are running against the same database then they interfere with each other.

Comment: It looks like a significant architectural issue in your application. It is very unnatural to block the same job run because another instance is running. In fact, usually, people aim quite the opposite to speed up the whole pipeline. I would suggest you to refactor the way tests address the database to avoid intersections, or spin up a new instance of the database for each job run.

Comment: Do you mean multiple builds uses the same build definition?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Agreed, the issue is I only have a single database for running the tests and I need to set it up for every test run, meaning I drop most of the tables and recreate them. Since this is a single database if another build is started while the first one is still running, it'll destroy the data that was set up for the first build.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT What I'd like to do is to be able to run only one build for the given build definition while all the others and in queue until the previous ones complete.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  In our case we are considering creating a PowerShell task that we add to the build that will not allow a build until the prior build has finished.  It won't be trivial, though, as I'll have to store a "queue" somewhere so that I make sure if 10 builds are triggered while the first one is running that they process in the correct order.  Perhaps that is something to think about for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We implemented a custom VSTS task to do this.  It works swimmingly.  Here is the code.

If creating a custom VSTS task isn't your thing - you can strip out the PowerShell.  Just have to pass the values as parameters instead.

## file structure

```
/ Project-Folder
    - extension-icon.png
    - extension-manifest.json
    / Tasks
        / KeepBuildSynchronous
            - icon.png
            - task.json
            - task.ps1
```

## extension-manifest.json

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "your-task-name",
    "name": "your-package-name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publisher": "your-publisher-account",
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],    
    "description": "your-description",
    "categories": [
        "Build and release"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "default": "extension-icon.png"        
    },
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "Tasks/KeepBuildSynchronous"
        }
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "12345678-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", <-- must match task.json id
            "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Tasks/KeepBuildSynchronous"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

## task.json

```
{
    "id": "12345678-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "name": "keepBuildSynchronous",
    "friendlyName": "Keep Build Synchronous",
    "description": "Only allow one build with the same build definition to run at a time",
    "helpMarkDown": "",
    "category": "Utility",
    "visibility": [
        "Build"
    ],
    "runsOn": [
        "Agent",
        "DeploymentGroup"
    ],
    "author": "-your team-",
    "version": {
        "Major": 1,
        "Minor": 1,
        "Patch": 1
    },
    "releaseNotes": "Initial release",
    "minimumAgentVersion": "1.91.0",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "waitTimeinMinutes",
            "type": "int",
            "label": "How many minutes do you want to wait before cancelling the build",
            "defaultValue": "15",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": ""
        }
    ],
    "instanceNameFormat": "Keep Build Synchronous",
    "execution": {
        "PowerShell3": {
            "target": "task.ps1"
        }
    }
}
```

## task.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param ()

Trace-VstsEnteringInvocation $MyInvocation
try {
    Import-VstsLocStrings "$PSScriptRoot\Task.json"

    # Get agent/build variables
    [string]$teamFoundationCollectionUri = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "system.teamFoundationCollectionUri"
    [string]$teamProjectId = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "system.teamProjectId"
    [string]$buildId = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "build.buildId"
    [int]$definitionId = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "system.definitionId" -AsInt
    [string]$accessToken = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "system.accessToken"

    # Get task inputs
    [int]$waitTimeinMinutes = Get-VstsInput -Name waitTimeinMinutes -AsInt

    [Object[]]$global:buildsByDefinition = $null
    [Object[]]$global:runningBuilds = $null

    function Get-Builds-By-Definition([int]$definitionId) {
        $url = "$teamFoundationCollectionUri/$teamProjectId/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&definitions=$definitionId"

        $type = "application/json"
        $headers = @{
            Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
        }
        $global:buildsByDefinition = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -ContentType $type -Method Get -Headers $headers).value
        $global:runningBuilds = $buildsByDefinition | Where-Object -Property "status" -Value "inProgress" -EQ
    }

    [datetime]$startedAt = Get-Date
    [datetime]$waitUntil = $startedAt.AddMinutes($waitTimeinMinutes)

    Get-Builds-By-Definition -definitionId $definitionId

    [string]$buildDefinitionName = $buildsByDefinition[0].definition.name

    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Build definition ..... $buildDefinitionName"
    Write-Host "Current build ........ $buildId"
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Started at ........... $startedAt"
    Write-Host "Willing to wait until  $waitUntil"
    Write-Host ""

    while (1 -eq 1) {

        if ((Get-Date) -gt $waitUntil) {
            Write-Host "Waited too long (cancelling)"
            throw "Waited longer than $waitTime minutes to start.  Cancelling."
        }

        if ($global:runningBuilds -eq $null) {
            Write-Host "No build running (weird, but ok...)"
            break
        }

        [int]$firstToGo = ($global:runningBuilds | Sort-Object -Property "Id")[0].Id

        if ($global:runningBuilds.Count -le 1 -or $buildId -le $firstToGo) {
            Write-Host "Your turn to shine"
            break
        } else {
            Write-Host "$($global:runningBuilds.Count) builds running. $firstToGo is next. (checking again)"
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
        }

        Get-Builds-By-Definition -definitionId $definitionId

    }
}
finally {
    Trace-VstsLeavingInvocation $MyInvocation
}
```

## create the .vsix file

```
tfx extension create --manifest-globs extension-manifest.json --rev-version
```

*I'll leave a little mystery and let you find out how to publish this to the marketplace and get it installed on your build agents*

Comment: ok -- this is where I'm lost -- I have the extension built and uploaded to the marketplace. It is only private. Now is this a task to add to a VSTS build definition or is it somehow added to the build agent. The final note says build agent - but what does that mean -- does the build agent need to be updated? And how do you add an extension to a build agent?

Comment: This document sums up where to go from here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/get-started/node?view=vsts#install-your-extension

Comment: I'll add to this that you may want to use "prejobexecution" instead of "execution" for the execution stage.  If the source control operations themselves would be problematic, this will put the wait in too late.  By using prejobexeuction it makes sure the script is run prior to the source being pulled.

Comment: The code will fail if you are doing a lot of builds. The HTTP request to retrieve the builds by definition will return the first 1000 builds sorted by completion date descending (I think). If you have more than 1000 completed builds, then the request will not include recently started builds and you'll see the "No build running (weird, but ok...)"-message and concurrent builds will be started. You need to add `&queryOrder=startTimeDescending` to the query.

Answer (score 1):

I appears this is not possible for manually triggered builds (arghh).
However, for CI builds, DevOps can be configured to bunch changes while a build is running.
Got to the "Triggers" tab of the build definition.
Check:

- **Enable continuous integration**
- **Batch changes while a build is in progress**

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure this at the Build level ([You can vote for this feature here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20452114-prevent-parallel-execution-of-the-same-build-defin)), but perhaps you can accomplish what you want at the phase level.

Look at the Parallelism options under each Phase.  Looks like you'll want to set this to "None" if you are seeing behavior contrary.  "None" is the default option for new builds.

[image: Parallelism Options]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. `None` means that the build will be run on a single agent as opposed to running the same build on many agents. It doesn't prevent multiple instances of the same build to be triggered on a different agents.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t such setting to control it, it is controlled by pipelines: [Concurrent build and release pipelines in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/licensing/concurrent-pipelines-ts#concurrent-processing-within-a-single-build-or-release).

You can disable other agents:

1. Go do Agent Queues admin page
2. Select the queue
3. Uncheck agent to disable it

On other hand, you can create a temp database with the name include build number, then they won't interfere with each other.

Comment: Yes, team database would be ideal. But the problem I have is I was given only a single database for running those tests so I can't just create a temp one for every single build.

Comment: @RaYell You need to disable other agents or you can create a new pool and queue with just an agent.

Comment: @RaYell, If disabling agents isn't for you, you could also accomplish this by adding a custom capability to a single (private) agent, then configure your build to require this custom capability.

Comment: @raterus Do you solve this issue with these ways? (disable agent, set capability)