# Azure Pipelines: How to block pipeline A if pipeline B is running

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

I have two pipelines (also called "build definitions") in azure pipelines, one is executing system tests and one is executing performance tests. Both are using the same test environment. I have to make sure that the performance pipeline is not triggered when the system test pipeline is running and vice versa.

What I've tried so far: I can access the Azure DevOps REST-API to check whether a build is running for a certain definition. So it would be possible for me to implement a job executing a script before the actual pipeline runs. The script then just checks for the build status of the other pipeline by checking the REST-API each second and times out after e.g. 1 hour.

However, this seems quite hacky to me. Is there a better way to block a build pipeline while another one is running?

Comment: Restrict them to run on a single agent, so there is only the potential for one to be running at a time.

Comment: This is not possible since I have to run the perf. tests on a single dedicated agent where the systests run on multiple agents in parallel.

Comment: @TobiasvonFalkenhayn Who trigger the tests and how?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk tests are triggered on merge to master as well as on a nightly schedule.

Comment: @TobiasvonFalkenhayn can you run the tests with Release pipeline? (if yes you can use gates to check)

Comment: Whats actually the difference between a pipeline and a release pipeline? Can i define yaml in release pipelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is private, the Microsoft-hosted CI/CD parallel job limit is one free parallel job that can run for up to 60 minutes each time, until you've used 1,800 minutes (30 hours) per month.

The self-hosted CI/CD parallel job limit is one self-hosted parallel job. Additionally, for each active Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber who is a member of your organization, you get one additional self-hosted parallel job.

And now, there isn't such setting to control different agent pool parallel job limit.But there is a similar problem on the community, and the answer has been marked. I recommend you can check if the answer is helpful for you. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860601/run-only-one-instance-of-a-build-on-vsts/49055425#49055425) is the link.

Comment: The marked answer does exactly what I was initially describing, creating a custom script which polls for running builds. Seems like this is the way to go then.

Comment: Did the link can help you achieve your need? If yes, you can accept the answer. It will convenient help other community users who have the same expected. If not, you can free to leave your comment here, and I will follow up in time. : )

Comment: It's my pleasure. Thanks.