# How to Run Azure Pipeline Builds Sequentially

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have created an Azure build pipeline using the 'classic editor' (i.e. not yaml). The build consists of two agent jobs:

**Job 1** - Build code and deploy to test enviornment using a single agent.

**Job 2** - Run tests against the test enviornment in parallel (using max 3 agents at a time).

My problem with this setup is if a build is triggered, and the tests are mid-run, if a second build is triggered, the code that is deployed to the test enviornment will be overwritten by the subsequent build, causing the test run in **Job 2** of the first build to fail.

Is it possible to tell the build pipeline to only trigger builds sequentially?

I have figured out how to use Azure DevOps API to check if the latest build has completed, however Im not sure how I can use it in the pipeline. Is it possible to do something like:

1 - Invote REST API to check status of latest build.

2 - Success Criteria met (i.e. the build has completed)? If yes continue build, if not wait a minute and check again.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft-hosted or a self-hosted agents?

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to control this in the Build options. Should work based on what you described. [image: Azure Devops Pipeline - Build Options]

**Edit**:
After looking again to your question, i noticed that you are running your tests after you deploy your app to test environment, so it means you run your tests during release, so you need to control the flow on your release and not on your buid. In order to do it, you should control on the maximum number of parallel deployments:

[image]

Comment: When I select that option all builds stay queued and never start.

Comment: After your build running finishes, the new ones do not start?

Comment: If I select that option, then save and queue a new build, the build stays in the queued state indefinitely.

Comment: Sorry, this would actually require to re-enable the pipeline again manually. The REST API does not allow to change that setting. In that case you can use a powershell script to fetch the builds running, by using build definition and then give the turn to the build to run based on your conditions. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860601/run-only-one-instance-of-a-build-on-vsts

Comment: Oh that looks very promising, weird that a custom script is required for something like this.

Comment: i changed my answer since i got in wrong direction with the question initially. you want to run your tests sequencially, so you want to run your releases to test environment sequentially, so you can achieve that by the image i shared.