# Azure Devops: Agent Jumping Around Different Builds

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I've noticed whenever I add stages or jobs into my pipeline and have multiple builds in the queue, a situation like this can occur: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDJUj.png)

In the case of the image:

- Stage 1 ran for the bottom commit
- Stage 1 ran for the top commit
- Stage 2 ran for the bottom commit
- Stage 2 ran for the top commit, etc...

Jobs seem to be trying to run in the pseudo-parralel format, but I only have 1 build agent. This results in super long build times, as it does one job for each, effectively doubling the time that the first one takes to finish. Is there any way that I can turn this off, and make the pipeline finish one build completely before moving onto the next?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Lawrence, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing we found that the order to trigger stage in different builds is out of control for [multi-stages yaml pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops), that's why you encounter this issue. However, if you use release pipeline, there is [Deployment queue settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#stage-triggers) so you can specify "`Deploy all in sequence`".

In addition, we found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860601/run-only-one-instance-of-a-build-on-vsts), which provides one way to develop a custom extension to make the pipeline finish one build completely before moving onto the next.

BTW, you could cancel other latter `notStarted` builds using PowerShell task which is the last step of each stage, thus the latter builds will be cancelled and then current build can be completely finished. The following is the sample PowerShell script, and you need to [create a PAT with full access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |   
      Write-Host "Start checking."
      $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitionId}&statusFilter=inProgress,notStarted&api-version=6.0"
      $connectionToken="PAT here"
      $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
      do
      {
          $pipelines = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
          $count = $pipelines.count
          if ($count -gt 1)
          {
              $lastestBuildId = $pipelines.value[-1].id
              $urlCancel = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/" + $lastestBuildId + "?api-version=6.0"
              $body = @{status="cancelling"} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
              Write-Host $urlCancel
              $result= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlCancel -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Patch #cancel the latter noStarted builds
          }
      } while($count -gt 1)
      Write-Host "It's my turn now."
```

Another workaround is that you could [create an environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#create-an-environment) named `approval-check` and [define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#approvals) for it, and then add the following `check` stage as the 1st stage in yaml pipeline, thus the new build must be approved then can start.

```
- stage: check
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
    environment: 'approval-check'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world
```